# Drupal 8-9 REST translations

Tags: rest, drupal-8, drupal-9

I can't send PATCH request to my REST API to send node with translations.

The error is 422 `Unprocessable Entity: validation failed. title: Title: this field cannot hold more than 1 values.`

I was trying JSON:API and REST, but the only way I found is to manually create translations, and after that update each translation separately.

The data I'm trying to PATCH to REST is

```
const data = {
  'type': 'charset',
  'title': [
    { 'value': sName1, 'lang': 'en' },
    { 'value': sName2, 'lang': 'ru' },
  ],
  'field_unicode_range': [{ 'from': iFrom, 'to': iTo }],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON:API does not seem to currently support translations (Nov 2021).
"does support PATCH requests on translations: updating translations is possible" [source](https://www.drupal.org/docs/core-modules-and-themes/core-modules/jsonapi-module/translations).
There does seem to be some work going on around this is [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2794431)

Comment: Yes, I read all this already, I was hoping that REST WS module doesn't have such problems.